# Choosing a set of CNNs for paper

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, convolutional-neural-network, inceptionresnetv2

There are so many CNNs out there and I am trying to do a comparison between some of them in my paper. Which networks should I include? Resnet, VGG, and Inception are obvious, but I would like three or four others. Which ones should I choose? There are so many variations out there like Xception, resnext, and ... that I am confused. Which of these networks are most used in the academic papers?

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends what kind of paper you are writing — you haven't provided too much information in that regard. You could discuss a selection of models that have scored the highest on [ImageNet](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-imagenet). Most of these networks have historical significance, and brought a new aspect to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Following list of CNNs are most popular in research papers. And since, you are doing a comparative study, it would be interesting to choose from the below list.

- Xception
- VGG16
- VGG19
- ResNet,
- ResNetV2
- InceptionV3
- InceptionResNetV2
- MobileNet
- MobileNetV2
- DenseNet
- NASNet

Comment: between dense net or InceptionResnet which one's result would be more interesting in a comparison? i mean which one is really different from resnet and vgg